# How can I remove a NavigableString from the tree?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am a bit confused: all tags have a `decompose()` method which allows to remove the tag from the tree in place. But what if I want to remove a `NavigableString`? It doesn't have such method:

```py
>>> b = BeautifulSoup('<p>aaaa <span> bbbbb </span> ccccc</p>', 'html.parser')
>>> b.p.contents[0]
'aaaa '
>>> type(b.p.contents[0])
<class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>
>>> b.p.contents[0].decompose()
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'decompose'
```

There's a way I managed to somewhat remove the `NavigableString` from the tree: by removing it from the content list:

```py
>>> b.p.contents.pop(0)
'aaaa '
>>> b
<p><span> bbbbb </span> ccccc</p>
```

The problem is that it is still present in the `strings` method response:

```py
>>> list(b.strings)
['aaaa ', ' bbbbb ', ' ccccc']
```

Which shows that it was wrong way to do. Besides, I am using `strings` in my code so this hacky solution is not acceptable, alas.

---

So the question is: how can I remove the specific `NavigableString` object from the tree?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `extract()` instead of `decompose()`

`extract()` removes a tag or string from the tree.

`decompose()` removes a tag from the tree.

```
b = BeautifulSoup('<p>aaaa <span> bbbbb </span> ccccc</p>', 'html.parser')
b.p.contents[0].extract()
print(b)
```

To Know more about it please check following link where you will find more details.
[BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Comment: Or use `.replace_with('')` to the same effect.

Comment: @JackFleeting yes, but it adds an empty string to `b.strings`. @KunduK's solution is perfect. Thank you!

Comment: @Dany - Correct and it indeed is.